# What's the name of this plant that has large, broad leaves with white spots?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I have this plant at home and I need to know its name so I can better take care of it. Here is a picture of the plant.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a [dumb cane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dumb_cane) (*Dieffenbachia*). While these are generally grown outside in the tropics, they can be grown indoors as they don't mind the shade. Wikipedia also lists some ideal growing conditions:

> The plant needs light but filtered sunlight through a window is usually sufficient. When the plant is brought home from the nursery, it will likely need repotting. The plant needs moderately moist soil. The soil should be fertilized with either regular liquid fertilizing or fertilizer pellets or spiky spikes. Leaves will periodically roll up and fall off to make way for new leaves. Yellowing of the leaves is generally a sign of problematic conditions, such as a nutrient deficiency in the soil.