# What is the medium-leaved, thick-stemmed plant?

Tags: identification, perennials

This plant was at the end of driveway, getting tossed by a previous owner. I'd like to care of it but I have zero idea what it is.

Does any one know a likely candidate?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a dieffenbachia, same as in [this question](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/2818/109), and you can also see images similar to yours in [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Dieffenbachia) (check images). If people agree, please vote it as a duplicate...

Comment: @yoda A dieffenbachia would have thicker stems and larger leaves.  If we could see the flower that would be a definitive key

Comment: @kevinsky Hmmm... I thought these were just small ones. Anyway, you probably know more about it than I do

Comment: @yoda I would oblige with a flower picture but it has none at the moment. Just from examining different pictures though it does appear to be Aglaonema.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to identify this house plant](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/34094/trying-to-identify-this-house-plant)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like an [Aglaonema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aglaonema), commonly called a Chinese Evergreen.  Their leaves come in a range of different variegation, so while the picture on the Wikipedia page doesn't look very much like yours, an [image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=chinese+evergreen&tbm=isch) shows several that are closer.

This plant looks like the leaves have been scorched by the sun, and it may not have been getting enough water (mine looked like that at one point after being packed away during a home remodel and not watered for *months*).  Fortunately, they're very durable when given the right conditions, so it should bounce right back if you can give it:

- shade or diffuse sunlight (I have mine at work where it's next to a west-facing window with Venetian blinds that are closed most of the time).
- moderate temperatures.  They don't like cold, so (depending on your climate) it might do best as a houseplant.
- even watering; they like to be kept damp all the time (though like I said, I have one that survived for months without water).

Comment: It's an aglo all right. They tolerate low light but do better with filtered bright light.