# What is this thick-stemmed houseplant with variegated leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I have a plant that I don't know the name of.

[image]

Could you please help me identify this plant?

Comment: Duplicate? http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4233/what-is-the-medium-leaved-thick-stemmed-plant

Comment: where are you located? do you have any idea how old the plant is? Does it always look like this, or does it sometimes flower or otherwise do something different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [Dieffenbachia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dieffenbachia).  The foliage patterns differ, but in the temperate climates, they are very popular house plants.  In the tropics, they can be grown outdoors.  I see a lot of them in atriums as well.  Here are [more pictures](https://www.google.com/search?q=dieffenbachia&client=firefox-a&hs=HhI&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=np&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=dHx-U-CrKJKcyASo1YGoBA&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1282&bih=604) showing the variety of foliage patterns and colorations.

By the way, one of the common names for this plant is "dumb cane" because the sap can cause numbness and swelling in the mouth and throat if ingested.  So watch pets and small kids around it if you have such at home.

Comment: Teresa has identified this correctly. A good thing to know is that the plant will regrow when cut back.  If it's too tall or droopy just cut the stem at the height you want and wait for the new buds.