# Trying to identify this house plant

Tags: identification, houseplants

I have this houseplant that is in tough shape. I want to learn about caring for it so I can attempt to revive it, but I don't know what kind of plant it is. Here are some pictures:

[image: Unknown Plant1]

[image: Unknown Plant2]

Comment: What does it say on that label inserted in the pot?

Comment: @Bamboo, the label in the pot just says "Assorted foliage". It must be a generic label they use for all the miscellaneous plants.

Answer (score 6):

This is an [aglaonema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aglaonema) which has been left to dry for too long but it has flowered and set those red seeds you can see in the picture

If you like the tough love approach then:

- cut all the stems a few inches above the soil line
- move to medium or diffuse light
- water sparingly until new growth appears and more once the leaves are out

This plant responds well to being cut back and can grow in a wide range of light conditions from low to high light that is diffuse.

Seeing as it has flowered I would not repot this year.  Next year add some new soil to the bottom of the pot and cut off the bottom inch of roots.

Pests are not seen in the pictures but can include mealy bug.

This is a very rugged low maintenance plant.

Comment: Hmm, that's difficult, he's got two different IDs, but you know an awful lot about houseplants - my id's based on the stems as much as anything, and the spathe/berry arrangement. But Im inclined that you're more likely to be right than I am, what do you think, cos the person needs to know - I'll scrap mine if you're 100%

Comment: Deleted mine, obviously - checked the leaves out properly this time!

Comment: @Bamboo  they are very similar but the main difference is the size of stems and leaves.

Comment: @kevinsky, you mention that this plant is very rugged and low maintenance, but I water it regularly (not too often, only when the soil is dry to the touch), and the leaves have slowly turned brown and die. I have another one, and it's doing the same thing. All my other plants are thriving. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: @AnthonyZampini Sometimes plants put a lot of energy into flowering.  I suggest cutting it back and letting it grow new shoots.  The dry papery leaves look like under watering in high light conditions.

Comment: @kevinsky, Thank you! I will try your suggestions.